# How to do operations on hidden vector of the decoder on every timestep and append it to the input of the next lstm unit

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

To implement attention in encoder-decoder, we have to take the hidden vector of an LSTM unit of the decoder, do several operation on it, to compute the attention weights. Now, my question is how can I individually take each hidden vector out from each LSTM unit in Keras?

This is how we initialize an lstm layer in Keras:

```
   lstm_layer = LSTM(num_units)(inputs)
```

Now, there would be so many LSTM units being initialized in this layer. How can I take each LSTM unit's hidden vector, do some operations on it and concat it with the input to the next lstm unit?

Note - I know that we can extract the hidden vector of all the lstm units, by setting the `return_sequences = true`. But, I want to take the hidden vector of all the lSTM units out, do some operations on it, and concat it with the input to the next lstm unit.

Edit - By **I want to take the hidden vector of all the LSTM units**, what I mean is that: Suppose there are **n timesteps** in total, so there will be **n number of lstm units**. Now, I want to take the output (i.e. the hidden vector) of lstm from timestep 0, do some operations on it (not to worry on this part, as it is to be implemented by the viewer himself based on which operations you want to do), and then concat it with the input to LSTM at timestep 1. And, implement all these operations on every lstm unit. So, in general: **Take hidden state of lstm from timestep t, do some operations on it and concat it with the input to lstm at timestep t+1**

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *I want to take the hidden vector of all the LSTM units*? The `return_sequences=True` argument does the same. You can use `return_states=True` also. See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/).\

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have edited the post, you can have a look at it